# TypeError: Failed to parse URL in getStaticProps and data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prerender, getstaticprops

I have a problem with getStaticProps in NextJS, i try to load specialists from API Route, but I get an error.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const specialists = await loadSpecialists();

    return {
        props: { specialists },
    };
};
```

```
export const loadSpecialists = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/specialists.js');
    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
};
```

```
if (req.method === 'GET') {
        const specialists = await database
            .collection('specialists')
            .find()
            .toArray();

        res.status(200).json({ specialists });
    }
```

I tried client-side rendering with useEffect and this works, but i need to prerender this page.

Answer (score 1):

Your url here

```
const response = await fetch('/api/specialists.js');
```

should be an absolute url. your client side code works because browser can handle the relative url

> By default, the browser handles relative URLs in links by prepending
> the correct scheme (protocol), server name, and directory information
> (including the junction) to the relative URL. The browser derives the
> prepended information from the location information of the page on
> which the link is located.

When you are on server, server cannot know the origin. you either hardcode absolute url

```
export const loadSpecialists = async () => {
    // or you couldnt set in env variable
    const response = await fetch(“http://localhost:3000/api/specialists.js”);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
};
```

Comment: It still didn't work. What value should I set on BASE_URL variable when i do development on localhost?